# Get absolute value in exponent of integrand

Tags: real-analysis, integration, absolute-value

Let $C$ be some constant and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Can I write the expression
$$
e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2+C\lvert x-z\rvert}\, dz
$$
in the form (or can I estimate from above by)
$$
e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2+C\lvert x\rvert+C\lvert z\rvert}\, dz?
$$

I really would like to have the summand $C\lvert x\rvert$ in the exponent of the integrand, because I want to cancel the factor $e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}$ in front of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

I would write

$\begin{array}\\
I(C, x)
&=e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2+C\lvert x-z\rvert}\, dz\\
&=e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\left(\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-z^2+C\lvert x-z\rvert}\, dz+\int_{x}^\infty e^{-z^2+C\lvert x-z\rvert}\, dz\right)\\
&=e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-z^2+C (x-z)}\, dz+e^{-C\lvert x\rvert}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-z^2+C(z-x)}\, dz\\
&=e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert+x)}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-z^2-Cz}\, dz+e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert-x)}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-z^2+Cz}\, dz\\
&=e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert+x)}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(z^2+Cz)}\, dz
+e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert-x)}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-(z^2-Cz)}\, dz\\
&=e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert+x)}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(z^2+Cz+C^2/4)+C^2/4}\, dz
+e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert-x)}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-(z^2-Cz+C^2/4)+C^2/4}\, dz\\
&=e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert+x)+C^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(z+C/2)^2}\, dz
+e^{-C(\lvert x\rvert-x)+C^2/4}\int_{x}^\infty e^{-(z-C/2)^2}\, dz\\
\end{array}
$

For any $x$,
one of the exponents
cancels
depending on the
sign of $x$.

Comment: I see! Is $I(C,x)<\infty$ for any x? The integrals in the last row are finite. That’s what I know already.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible to write the integral in my question such that $C\lvert x\rvert$ appears in the exponent of the integrand? ... just for curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use the triangle inequality,
$$  0 \leq |x - z| \leq |x| + |z|  $$
(on the right; the left is automatic from the definition of absolute value).  If $C \geq 0$, 
$$  0 \leq C|x - z| \leq C|x| + C|z|  $$
and monotonicity gives ,
$$  \mathrm{e}^{-z^2} \leq \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x - z|} \leq \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x| + C|z|}  \text{.}  $$ 
However, if $C < 0$, 
$$  0 \geq C|x - z| \geq C|x| + C|z|  $$
and monotonicity gives ,
$$  \mathrm{e}^{-z^2} \geq \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x - z|} \geq \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x| + C|z|}  \text{.}  $$ 
So whether you get the kind of bound you say depends on the sign of $C$.

An entirely different way to go (that perhaps clarifies why the sign of $C$ matters): \begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x - z|} \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x - z|} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \int_{x}^\infty \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C|x - z|} \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C(x - z)} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \int_{x}^\infty \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + C(z - x)} \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
&= \mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{x}^\infty \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2 + Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
&= \mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
- \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-x}^{-\infty} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u  & \hspace{-.9in} \begin{bmatrix} u=-z \\ \mathrm{d}u = -\mathrm{d}z \end{bmatrix}  \\
&= \mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-\infty}^{-x} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    \\
&= \begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-\infty}^{-x} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    &, x \geq 0\\
\mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^x \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-\infty}^{-x} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    &, x < 0  \\
\end{cases}  \\
&= \begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-|x|}^{|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    &, x \geq 0  \\
\mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-|x|}^{|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    &, x < 0  \\
\end{cases}  \\
&= \begin{cases}
\left( \mathrm{e}^{Cx} + \mathrm{e}^{-Cx} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{Cx} \int_{-|x|}^{|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z    &, x \geq 0  \\
\left( \mathrm{e}^{Cx} + \mathrm{e}^{-Cx} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{-Cx}\int_{-|x|}^{|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u    &, x < 0  \\
\end{cases}  \\
&= \left(\mathrm{e}^{C|x|} + \mathrm{e}^{-C|x|}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{-|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-z^2  - Cz} \,\mathrm{d}z
+ \mathrm{e}^{C|x|}\int_{-|x|}^{|x|} \; \mathrm{e}^{-u^2 - Cu} \,\mathrm{d}u  \text{.}
\end{align*}
After multiplying through by your pre-factor, exactly the cancellation you want will occur on the right term and will partially occur in the left term.

Comment: How do you get the very last row from the row before? That’s hard to see for me

Comment: @user710655 : Added a couple more steps.  You should think of decomposing the two intervals of integration into $(-\infty, -|x|]$ and $[-|x|, |x|]$, in the case when $x \geq 0$ and in the case when $x < 0$.  Then assemble the two cases.  You always get contributions on $(-\infty,-|x|]$ from both integrals and a contribution to $[-|x|, |x|]$ only from one.